# How to map data:image/png;base64 in :

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, object, mapping

```
result :
{0: {name1: 'data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfE…o7ZEAAABQlSFM6AAAwBv/Dwx2OpU7DJNTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'}
1: {name2: data:image/png;base64, KJGSAHGsvahvAFGD54gfCfghcg}}
```

I am using map using react to display the base64 image, I am stuck in mapping the image because of the indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: It's not a valid JS array, maybe shape of your data is like this: `{ 0: {name1:'value'}, 1: {name2: 'value'}, ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const data = {
  0: {name1: 'data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfE…o7ZEAAABQlSFM6AAAwBv/Dwx2OpU7DJNTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'},
  1: {name2: 'data:image/png;base64, KJGSAHGsvahvAFGD54gfCfghcg'}
}

const images = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key][`name${Number(key)+1}`])

console.log(images);
```

If you want to use it to render `JSX` to create an array of imgaes you can do it like this:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => <img key={key} src={ data[key][`name${Number(key)+1}`] }  />)
```